# List with 2018 JCR impact factors, categories and quartiles

Tags: impact-factor

I am looking for a PDF document or list that contains the new 2018 JCR Impact Factor for all journals, but not only showing Impact Factor, but also adding info about categories and quartile. Of course you can go to JCR website and look each time for each journal but this is very time consuming

Comment: You won't find such a list. The licence of Web of Science doesn't allow any accumulation of impact factors like in the form lists. Even Elsevier is not allowed to post a list of their journals including the impact factor. It's only allowed to put the journal impact factor on the website of the journal.

Comment: yes but you know that in some places people put these lists anyway. for instance sci-hub like sites

Comment: A quick google search gave multiple related answers, I am guessing this might be useful: https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php

Comment: Have you asked at the library of your institution? This is typically the kind of information that they get by subscription.

Comment: @TheHiary I was talking about ISI JCR, not Scimago

Comment: It might be useful to explain (briefly) what you want this information for, since that may influence the answer. For example, if you want the information for bibliometric research then Clarivate (the new name for ISI) may be able to provide the data, whereas if you want to know the impact factor for all the journals in a specific field, this can be downloaded from the InCites website. If you can provide a bit more detail, people may be able to provide more-detailed advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326007449_2019_Journal_Impact_Factor_SCI_JCR_2019) is a PDF uploaded to ResearchGate, which seems to be the most recent list.

Comment: this is not what I am looking for, since it does not contain information about categories and quartiles